# "Resource temporarily unavailable" error trying to run nodejs app in AS/400

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

I need to connect a NodeJS to AS/400 server. In order to do that, I installed NodeJS in AS/400 with IBM documentation and tryed (succesfully) to send and receive data with Class iDataQueues (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Toolkit%20for%20i%20APIs?section=Class%20iDataQueue) between AS/400 server and my develope computer. My next step was to run a program (Class iPgm) to received some data.

I'm running my test with

> /path/to/ibm/node/installation/node /home/test/app.js"

and I'm getting a "node[537]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable" error, but I have no idea what is the problem:

- Server has enough resources
- There are not any node running in server
- There are not any changes in server config between iDataQueue and iPgm tests
- I have root privileges

I think my code is not the problem because I dont' even run it ¬¬'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by running node in QSH. By default QSH does not support running threads, so any attempt to create a thread will result in that "Resource temporarily unavailable" message. This can fixed by setting the environment variable QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y prior to running QSH, using QP2TERM, or using SSH.